# Android, openGL lag in jni when touching screen

Tags: android, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0, android-ndk, lag

I am currently testing out all the features that a need in my game on the Android platform. I have only modified the hello-gl2 sample code, and added some textures, VBO's, FBO's and simple shaders in two rendering passes.

The thing is that when I let the app run with out touching the screen, i have about 35-45 fps. But if I start touching the screen continuously, the rendering starts to lag! So is this a problem because input and rendering is in the same thread (as a thinks it is?), is it even possible to fix? If I can't fix that lag, my game is probably not going to run good enough to bee playable. (Is has some heavy rendering stuff)

//Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to android development but found the touch handler to be very laggy also. The default sample is newing up an object and doing this quite a lot - this is bound to make the garbage collector angry. I managed to get it to perform in a less laggy way by calling 'Thread.sleep(10);' inside the run function.

I imagine that replacing the 'new Runnable' with a circular buffer of objects would improve performance but I haven't investigated this yet. I'm the touch events seem to occur on a seperate thread and this may cause complications.

```
Override public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event)
    {
        queueEvent(


        new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {

                int action = event.getAction();
                //do your handling here
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I see you mentioned Jni. Sorry that this answer only refers to Java code. I haven't tried doing a full game loop using Jni yet.

Comment: Well, from what i have read, you can't do a full game loop in jni unless you use android 2.3, i'm using 2.0, but I'm not trying to do the whole game in c. I only call a jni function that simulates the game and renders everything in c code. Then i return to the normal android java code. I plan to fetch input in java and sending it with the jni call and do my whole game in jni tough. So what I basically need to know is how to approach this problem with performens in mind.

Comment: Your approach sounds similar to mine; I have some jni code for buffer handling routines but the rest is currently in Java. Have you tried putting a little delay in there? It might stop your game from being overwhelmed by touch messages.

Comment: When I call sleep, my rendering stops. So apparently the hello-gl2 sample is not rendering in a separate thread. I have looked at some other code samples that's suppose to run in different threads, but none of them are complete code and I can't wrap my head around how to make the renderer run in it's own thread... gaah! Any healp would be much appreciated"